# How to perform an ND coordinate sweep using numpy meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a grid of sampling points in 4 dimensions. I want the points to span from 0 to 10 with equal spacing in each direction. I tried a few iterations of `np.meshgrid` calls, but I am sure I am doing something wrong. What is the proper way to create these points?

```
import numpy as np
XL, XU = (0, 10) # lower/upper bounds
MD = 4 # 4 dimensions
x = np.linspace(XL, XU, 20)
np.meshgrid(*[x for ____ in range(MD)])[0].reshape(MD, x.size ** MD // MD).T

array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       ...,
       [10., 10., 10., 10.],
       [10., 10., 10., 10.],
       [10., 10., 10., 10.]])
```

My current best solution has repeated elements, so I'm sure I must have done something wrong. What has gone wrong here? How can I create the desired grid of equally spaced points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meshgrid` returns the coordinates in the corresponding arrays. In your case for 4 dimensions:

```
xx, yy, zz, ww  = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, w)
```

That means, `xx` will contains all the `x` coordinates while `yy` all the `y` coordinates and so on. Further more `xx.shape == yy.shape == ...` and is equal to the number of points on the grid.

To get your desired result, might be `stack`:

```
# point as rows 
out = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*[x]*MD), axis=-1).reshape(-1, MD)

array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.52631579],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.05263158],
       ...,
       [10.        , 10.        , 10.        ,  8.94736842],
       [10.        , 10.        , 10.        ,  9.47368421],
       [10.        , 10.        , 10.        , 10.        ]])

# or point as columns
out = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*[x]*MD).reshape(MD, -1)

array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ..., 10.        , 10.        , 10.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ..., 10.        , 10.        , 10.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ..., 10.        , 10.        , 10.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.52631579,  1.05263158, ...,  8.94736842,  9.47368421, 10.        ]])
```

Comment: So is numpy's meshgrid not the right approach here?

Comment: In someway it is. It just stores the data differently, and need further processing. See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

It looks quite complitated to imagine what was done in Quang's answer so I decided to visualise these tricks in case `x` consists of two points:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm still having trouble wrapping my mind around this. I'm offering a small bounty for a more detailed answer, in case you want to expand this. I see a lot of value in your answer, but it's hard for me to understand all of it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so @QuangHoang's answer is:

```
QH = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*[x]*MD), axis=-1).reshape(-1, MD)
```

While yours is:

```
KJ = np.meshgrid(*[x for ____ in range(MD)])[0].reshape(MD, x.size ** MD // MD).T
```

What's the difference?  Well for starters:

```
QH.shape
Out: (160000, 4)

KJ.shape
Out: (40000, 4)
```

You're missing some points.  Exactly 1/4 of them, in fact.  Why?

```
KJ = np.meshgrid(*[x for ____ in range(MD)])[0].reshape(MD, x.size ** MD // MD)
                                            ^^^
```

You calculate 4 arrays, but only use one of them.  Let's look at that array:

```
grid_0 = np.meshgrid(*[x for ____ in range(MD)])[0]
grid_0

   [[[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ],
     ...,
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ]],

    [[ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579],
     [ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579],
     [ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579],
     ...,
     [ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579],
     [ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579],
     [ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579]],

    [[ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158],
     [ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158],
     [ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158],
     ...,
     [ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158],
     [ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158],
     [ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158]],

    ...,

    [[ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842],
     [ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842],
     [ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842],
     ...,
     [ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842],
     [ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842],
     [ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842]],

    [[ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421],
     [ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421],
     [ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421],
     ...,
     [ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421],
     [ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421],
     [ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421]],

    [[10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ],
     [10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ],
     [10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ],
     ...,
     [10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ],
     [10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ],
     [10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ]]],

...


   [[[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ],
     ...,
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
       0.        ,  0.        ]],

    [[ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579],
     [ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579],
     [ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579],
     ...,
     [ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579],
     [ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579],
     [ 0.52631579,  0.52631579,  0.52631579, ...,  0.52631579,
       0.52631579,  0.52631579]],

    [[ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158],
     [ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158],
     [ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158],
     ...,
     [ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158],
     [ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158],
     [ 1.05263158,  1.05263158,  1.05263158, ...,  1.05263158,
       1.05263158,  1.05263158]],

    ...,

    [[ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842],
     [ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842],
     [ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842],
     ...,
     [ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842],
     [ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842],
     [ 8.94736842,  8.94736842,  8.94736842, ...,  8.94736842,
       8.94736842,  8.94736842]],

    [[ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421],
     [ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421],
     [ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421],
     ...,
     [ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421],
     [ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421],
     [ 9.47368421,  9.47368421,  9.47368421, ...,  9.47368421,
       9.47368421,  9.47368421]],

    [[10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ],
     [10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ],
     [10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ],
     ...,
     [10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ],
     [10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ],
     [10.        , 10.        , 10.        , ..., 10.        ,
      10.        , 10.        ]]]]
```

And its shape:

```
grid_0.shape
Out: (20, 20, 20, 20)
```

Basically, it's a 20 x 20 x 20 cube filled with `x[i]` for 0=<i<20.

I can't upload pictures from my current location, but this code will show the effect

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(grid_0.flatten())
plt.plot(grid_0[0].flatten())
```

It's basically 20 sets of stairs, and the first set of stairs starts at 0 for the first 400 points. And ends with 10 for the last 100 points.  This is why when you reshape it to:

```
grid_0.reshape(MD, x.size ** MD // MD).T
```

your first 100 points are [0,0,0,0] and your last 100 are [10, 10, 10 ,10]

In addition:

```
plt.plot(np.meshgrid(*[x for ____ in range(MD)])[-1][0,0].flatten())
plt.plot(np.meshgrid(*[x for ____ in range(MD)])[-2][0,0].flatten())
```

on a 2D scale it's easy to see that one dimension is moving stepwise while the other is moving continuously, creating the grid.  By losing the 3 other dimesnions, you lose the grid and are left with stairs.

Now let's look at how you should have done it:

```
 QH = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*[x]*MD), axis=-1).reshape(-1, MD)
```

Notice it doesn't use only the first dimension, but all of them.

By stacking those dimensions on the last axis you make sure every combination is in that axis (in this case it's the 5th dimension before reshaping).  It's important to stack on the *last* axis becasue `numpy` reshapes based on broadcasting rules - last dimension first.  This way the last dimension is maintained through the reshape from (20,20,20,20,4) to (160000, 4).